# Restated financial statements versus the original

Tags: balance-sheet, cash-flow, financial-statements

Is there any reason you would want to look into the original statements if you have the restated available?

Comment: Could you elaborate how it is related to personal finance ?

Comment: I want to invest in stocks, and I am contemplating the reasons for why someone would want to look at the original statements if the restated ones are available

Comment: Add that in your post to clarify. It doesn't seems so from your post.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would want to compare the differences between the original sheets and the restated sheets.  A lot of times this is simply a recategorization of an asset or a liability or something but I'd be wary if a company has a habit of restating its financials.